# Looking for centralising an image in html blocks on Squarespace

Tags: html, css

I'm new to coding and are looking for help with centralizing an image (well 6 in total) on my squarespace site. see example below.

[**View Site Here**](http://www.thedistancelive.com/review) -- The photos are leaning to the left hand side of the blocks. As you can probably see, I've tried to centralize the text but it's still not looking right.

I've read through the internet, trying different searches but I'm having no luck...

Also, if anyone does have any advice could they please advise me as to how to place the code into something of this nature:

```
<div id="first" class="image">
        <img class="photo" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55b94761e4b0d425914723a8/t/561e2c53e4b093c102b5990c/1444818003995/alex+and+heidi.png"/>

    <div>
        <p class="names">Heidi Stenhouse
      <br><span style="color:rgb(153,153,153); font-size:13px; line-height:20px"> <span class="formob">-----</span>Wedding</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class='layer'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something of THIS nature: :)


<div id="first" class="image">
        <img class="photo" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/55b94761e4b0d425914723a8/t/561e2c53e4b093c102b5990c/1444818003995/alex+and+heidi.png"/>

    <div>
        <p class="names">Heidi Stenhouse
      <br><span style="color:rgb(153,153,153); font-size:13px; line-height:20px"> <span class="formob">-----</span>Wedding</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class='layer'>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: add text-align: center to class "sqs-block-content" and remove float: left from class "photo". Also, remove extra spaces in span "formob"

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I'm so sorry i'm a complete beginner here.. where do I put text-align: center please? x

Comment: to the "sqs-block-content" class, like this:
.sqs-block-content { text-align: center }

Comment: Hi Ricardo, Thanks again for your reply. I'm still so confused, sorry.

Do i place sqs-block-content { text-align: center } into the code block or in custom CSS area in squarespace?

Comment: you must put in your custom css. The same for  .photo { float: none }

Comment: Thankyou so much. Could i just ask one more quick question please?

Comment: How would I now centralise the text to be exactly in line with the photos?

Www.thedistancelive.com/review

Comment: Thanks for your help :) x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here

```css
.photo {
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 25px;
    width: 85px;
}
```

you need to remove `margin-right:25px` and the text will be centered with the `img`

Comment: No problem, you Welcome `:)`

Comment: Have a great night x